# Set dimnames of a matrix

Tags: r, row, names

I am trying to set the row names of a matrix from a list of names I read in through csv.read(). It just sets the row names to "1".

```
labels<-read.csv('labels.csv',header = F,sep=';',comment.char='',as.is=F)
labels
       V1     V2      V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8      V9     V10    V11    V12
1 ball11   ball9 ball12 ball2 ball6 ball7 ball1 ball3 ball10 ball18 ball29 ball4
row.names(M)<-labels
```

Where M is a 12x12 double matrix.

This is what I get

```
> row.names(M)
[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into problems because you read the data in as `factor`s. Convert them to characters first.

Since you're just dealing with one line, you can try:

```
row.names(M) <- sapply(labels, as.character)
```

Comment: hmm, at first I thought the problem was that the names were in a `list`...but that works. You'd think `as.is` would prevent the factor conversion.

Comment: oops, I misread. I swear that was a `T` a minute ago ;). Another reason to spell out `TRUE` and `FALSE`...

Comment: Interestingly, `row.names` will work with a list, and with a factor, but not with a list of factors... go figure.

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your previous comment, but
    row.names(M)<-unlist(labels)
works. thanks

Comment: If you change your call to `read.csv` so that `as.is=TRUE`, you don't need to call `unlist`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `scan` instead: `labels <- scan('labels.csv', what='', sep=';', quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: @HongOoi, this may be an unwanted feature caused by some sanity check in the primitive function `'dimnames<-'`.